# How I align two spinners evenly?(%50-%50)

Tags: android, android-layout

I mean I have one line and I want to put 2 spinner in there with horizontal. I want to put them evenly. But I dont set it.When I set it 3,3 inc screens , it is problem with other screens because I use dp . What do I use? Lineerlayout or relative? Anad How I set them?
Thanks.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >





        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="309dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

THIS IS IMG TO SHOW MY PROBLEM : http://img4host.net/viewer.php?img=220942354fe421eb92ec5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use weight sum in Linear layout .....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I tick your answerin in 4 min

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the width dynamically independent to devices,

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

metrics.heightPixels;
int width=metrics.widthPixels;
```

Now split the width into two, `width=width/2;` and set the width to your spinners in your Activity dynamically.

```
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: thanks for answering. How I set in code? can you write some code. thanks

Comment: thanks for answering If I give 2 correct answer I tick your answer but below answer it is super. yours too ,sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight="float value here"` inside your spinners. That should do the trick.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_weight) for explanation.